# Appending raw input to a list

Tags: python, list

This is the simplest of exercises. I just don't understand why it wont work.

Here's my code:

```
hobbies = []
for i in range(3):
    hobby = raw_input("Name a hobby")
    hobbies = hobbies.append(hobby)
```

Basically I want to ask my user 3 times to name one of his hobbies, and store them in a list. But for some reason I'm getting this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/hobbies.py", line 4, in <module>
    hobbies = hobbies.append(hobby)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

which I don't really understand.

Comment: I have no idea why these hyperlinks to adverts are there. I didn't put them in.

Comment: Could someone explain why theres so many adverts in my post if I didn't put them in there???

Comment: you could consider accepting one of the answers below. Remember that you get a +2 reputation by doing that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `hobbies = hobbies.append()`. Instead use `hobbies.append()` only.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `append()` will change the list in-place. And when you call this function no value is returned.

The first time you get a `None` value for the variable `hobbies`. The second time you try to call the `append()` method for a `None` value...